# React, Write In Radio Option

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, radio-group

I wanted to figure out a way to have a list of options for radio button, but also be able to write in an answer for the last option using Material UI. Figuring out how to hook up the TextField to the RadioGroup took a few hours, so maybe this can help someone else too.

[image: Radio with Write In Option]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to keep track of actively selected radio button in RadioGroup, not in FormControlLabel, and have the fields update each other.

Full solution on this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-pine-644qo?file=/src/App.js

Here is the meat:

```
const RadioWritein = (props) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("");
  const [writeInOption, setWriteInOption] = useState("");
  const handleRadioChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleWriteInChange = (event) => {
    setWriteInOption(event.target.value);
    handleRadioChange(event);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <RadioGroup value={selectedValue} onChange={handleRadioChange}>
        {props.options.map((option) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            value={option.name}
            label={option.label}
            control={<Radio />}
          />
        ))}
        <FormControlLabel
          value={writeInOption}
          label={
            <TextField
              label="other"
              defaultValue=""
              onChange={handleWriteInChange}
            />
          }
          control={<Radio />}
        />
      </RadioGroup>
      Value: {selectedValue}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RadioWritein
        options={[
          { name: "a", label: "a" },
          { name: "b", label: "b" }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```